# Task Execution Working Correctly. Package Execution Not Working Correctly

Tags: ssis

I have created an SSIS solution (using SQL SERVER 2012) to extract data from ServiceNow. All the tasks are wrapped in a Sequence Container. When I right click on the Sequence Container and click Execute Task the package behaves as expected. It extracts the data from ServiceNow and performs the rest of the etl. However when I click Execute Package from the Solution Explorer the package successfully completes but it does not extract any data from Service Now.

I have played around with settings and different package designs but with no change in behavior. I can execute with true success at the task level but not the package level. This behavior is even apparent after deployment. I can execute with success from the SSISDB but with no data extraction. When I hook the deployed package to a job I still get no data extraction.

My thinking it has to be some kind of bug or hidden proxy setting because I only get true success (with data extraction) when I manually execute at the task level - i.e. the Sequence Container.

I have been using SSIS for a couple years now and have not come across this issue. Hopefully someone can help or have some ideas.

Comment: What all is going on in your control flow? This sounds like there is something, perhaps an expression, controlling behaviour prior to the Sequence Container resulting in either the sequence not firing or perhaps a parameter makes your SN query find no results.

Comment: In SSMS, expand the Integration Services catalog and look at the Execution Reports for an instance of a run. Do you see activity for the sequence container and whatever it contains, probably a data flow in there? That will at least tell you whether those tasks are getting the green light to run. If that's the case, then there is something with the data acquisition bit, probably your data flow, that is off versus an expression on say an Enable property that is getting flipped.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a variable at the package level that is being used in expressions for multiple ADONET.SqlCommand

Comment: I got it. Thank you billinkc that helped me think in the right direction. I needed to update the Package Property Delay Validation from False to True. That solved the issue. I guess the SSIS package needed the extra time to valid the variable and expression.

Comment: Post your resolution as an answer if you would so this gets marked as resolved

Comment: Blinkc...I tried that originally. Because I am so new to stackoverflow (been reading for years but only just opened the account) I can not post the answer for 8 hours.

Comment: Remember to do it tonight/tomorrow then ;)

Comment: Will do...thanks for the help getting my mind in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I needed a break and to think about this clearly. I needed to update the Package Property Delay Validation from False to True. That solved the issue. I guess the SSIS engine needed the extra time to validate the variable and expressions set up within the package.